# telnet connection stalls websocket server

Tags: php, websocket, telnet

I have a websocket server that occasionally stalls on incoming connections. I can reproduce this behavior by connecting via `telnet server.tld 8080` and not typing anything.

When I enagage the connection via telnet but do not type anything then the server detects the incoming connections but the `stream_socket_accept()` call will stall for one minute. Exactly 60 seconds. Every time.

What's making this situation worse is the fact that `stream_socket_accept()` completely ignores the timeout variable AND `default_socket_timeout`.

What could I do to abort the stalling?

Answer (score 1):

The default_socket_timeout was ignored, because the socket server runs as php-cli. So the php.ini file loaded is different to the apache module version of php. I did not know this. While stream_socket_accept does not work properly, a timeout can be forced by `ini_set('default_socket_timeout',$timeInSeconds);`